# How do I overcome "edit summary must be at least 10 characters"?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

When I try to edit an answer by another user, it always says:

> Your edit summary must be at least 10 characters.

I tried to add some useful code to the related question and format some lines.

How do I overcome this restriction?

Comment: Below the editing box there's an edit summary box where you are expected to add a description of your changes.  This will show up when people view the versions.

Comment: Below the tags box and just above the "submit edit" button.

Answer (score 6):

You can overcome this restriction by filling in the edit summary. :)

> [image]

Comment: The error message actually appears in a small box next to the edit summary, with an arrow pointing to the edit summary, and jiggles back and forth. Just sayin'.